# How to pass an object inside an object from a Controller to a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Here is my action Create of my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Pedido pedido)
{

     List<Produto> lista = new List<Produto>();

     if (ModelState.IsValid)
     {
          //Cliente cliente = unitOfWork.ClienteRepository.Busca(pedido.ClienteId);
          Produto produto = unitOfWork.ProdutoRepository.Busca(pedido.ProdutoId);
           lista.Add(produto);
            pedido.produtos = lista;
            //pedido.cliente = cliente;
            unitOfWork.PedidoRepository.Adiciona(pedido);
            unitOfWork.Salva();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }
}
```

My object pedido is ok...with the object cliente ok...but when the object pedido goes to the view Index...somehow the object cliente that is inside the object pedido is lost...

Here is my View Index:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProjetoZeus.Models.Pedido>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Lista de Pedidos</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Adicionar Novo", "Create")
</p>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Pedidos</legend>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ID)</th>
            <th>Produto</th>
            <th>Preço</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.cliente)</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
           <tr>
               <td>
                   @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.ID)
               </td>
               <td>
                   @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.produtos[0].Nome)
               </td>
               <td>
                   @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.produtos[0].Preco)
               </td>
               <td>
                   @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.cliente.NomeCliente)
               </td>
           </tr>

        }
    </table>

</fieldset>
```

In the View the only thing that is null is my object Cliente and my List.

Comment: What is your actual question. You have shown a POST method for `Create()` which you claim is working (its irrelevant), and the you show a view for `Index()` which you claim is not, yet you have not even shown the code for the `Index()` method (which is relevant)

Comment: i didnt know for sure what was my problem...I solved now in my model i did not declared two variables with VIRTUAL

Comment: You have not even shown your model. You should delete the question. Its of no use to anyone and others wont waste their time trying to add answers

Comment: i cant delete just a moderator...moderator if you please ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you really need is

```
return View("Index", lista);
```

instead of

```
return RedirectToAction("Index")
```

which redirects the browser to "Index" action of the controller.

Answer (score 0):

The code line `return RedirectToAction("Index");` redirects the user to your `Index` view (of type HttpGet). Based on assumption that `Index` action fetches the `IEnumerable<ProjetoZeus.Models.Pedido>` from DB. If updated DB value have updated 'Cliente' then it will be null.